# Refresh div using ajax or php

Tags: php, ajax

i am using a function to show and hide div and it's working fine , in one of these divs there is a table , i have a function (php) to search and filter the table and it's a;so working but the problem is when i press the search button(submit in php) the page refreshes (admin.php) showing the first (#pending) . Can i do the php function and stay in the same div(#users without the page refreshing to the begenning. 
These are the function that i am using:

1-hide and show:

```
    $(function(){
     $('#1').on('click',function(){
         $('#pending').show();
      $('#users').hide();
      $('#books').hide();
      $('#uploadbook').hide();
    });
    $('#2').on('click',function(){
      $('#users').show();
      $('#books').hide();
      $('#uploadbook').hide();
      $('#pending').hide();
    });
     $('#3').on('click',function(){
      $('#users').hide();
      $('#books').show();
      $('#uploadbook').hide();
      $('#pending').hide();
    });
     $('#4').on('click',function(){
      $('#users').hide();
      $('#books').hide();
      $('#uploadbook').show();
      $('#pending').hide();
    });


});
```

2- refresh div button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#search").click(function(){
  $("#users").load("/s/admin.php");
 });
});
```

3-search(php):

```
<?php 
require_once 'connection.php';

 session_start();

 if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    // search in all table columns
    // using concat mysql function
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `r` WHERE CONCAT(`id`, `username`,`email`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);

}
 else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `r`";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "x");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}
?>
```

I just want to stay where i am after the function is done , and i hope these details are enough for anyone to help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: It really sounds like you're just asking, "How do I use AJAX?"  Have you started with any tutorials or examples?

Comment: I am using ajax already , but the problem is i am using the button to search in php can this button be used is ajax to refresh the div.

Comment: Yes, you can use AJAX to fetch data from the server and modify the contents of the page without refreshing the page.  That's exactly what AJAX is for, really.  So where are you using it?  What attempt have you made and in what way is it not working as expected?  The code shown has no button, no AJAX code, no div, no attempt to refresh the contents of the div, etc.  (It does, however, have a glaring SQL injection vulnerability.  Unrelated to the question, but you *really* should fix that by using prepared statements and query parameters.)

Comment: There is one major reasons the page refreshes once you click the Button.  @yasserh   **You are not preventing the default behaviour of the button**. If the Button is tied to a Form, clicking on the Button must certainly submit the form unless explicitly prevented from doing so. Again; **the Functionality you wish to implement can only be done with AJAX**. But you said you are already using AJAX. Can we see your AJAX Code?

Comment: I used jQuery code , i edited the question.

Comment: "*I am using ajax already ...*" But, I'm not able to see any AJAX code.

Comment: @yasserh: How does `$("#users").load("/s/admin.php")` execute that search?  It doesn't supply the POST parameters that the PHP code is looking for.  As for the page refreshing, the comment above from Poiz is likely correct.  If the default action for the button click (code you haven't shown us) is to post a form or in some way refresh the page, then your click handler for that button will need to prevent that.  Look into `preventDefault()` in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry , it was a jQuery code , i tried to show the #users div after the form is submitted and it's not working              $("#myform").submit(function() {
     $('#users').show();
      $('#books').hide();
      $('#uploadbook').hide();
      $('#pending').hide();
});